# How do I get IntelliJ 10 to deploy a project that uses JiBX?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, spring-ws, jibx

I have a multi module maven project (a war) on of these modules utilized executes a post-compile step to update JiBX bindings.

I would like to use IntelliJ to build and deploy this project. However I can't seem to figure out how to get IntelliJ to kick off the JiBX compiler. Any thoughts?

If it isn't possible to kick off the JiBX compiler, I'd like IntelliJ to treat the module that requires the JiBX compilation step as a "normal" dependency and simply pull the appropriate jar from my local maven repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have this already... in your IntelliJ run/debug configuration check the "Run Maven Goal" checkbox and choose jibx:bind from the jibx entry under plugins.